# What is the most efficient and concurrent way to implement a public API for an existing command-line program?

Tags: api, http, sockets, tcp, pyqt

An existing command-line program generates some output when called with some parameters, and then exits.

I would like to modify this program to run on an event loop, and listen through a public API (could be in same machine). There seem to be multiple ways of implementing this:

- make the API external to the program and do system calls
- turn the program into a library, and include the necessary functionality into the API itself
- local sockets (like a TCP line server, for eg.)
- HTTP server (producing JSON, XML, etc)

Considering efficiency under load, concurrency and scalability, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api-design also depends on the clients, maybe you can give some more information:

- kind of client (real user, technical client polling things, etc.)
- trust-level of clients (open to anyone, closed set of clients to be authenticated)

Regarding scalability requirements:

- how many users
- expected load (peak + average)

Another idea could be a simple ssh-server so anyone can execute the script from outside:

```
$ ssh user@yourhost.com yourCLIProgram.sh -param1 value1 -param2 value2
```

Then you don't need a overhead of event-listening loop.

What does the program do in more detail?